# Possible to split item over 150lbs (ups) into smaller boxes to calculate shipping?

Tags: shipping, ups

I have come across an issue where we cannot calculate shipping on an item over 150lbs.

I first have tried the solution outlined here http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/179546/#t234403
(set max. package weight -150lbs and Packages request type - divide to equal weights)

Now this works for an entire cart of multiple items.  For example if you have a cart with 2 items and a total weight of 160lbs, it will split the cart into separate boxes and give a rate.  However if you have one item in a cart at 160lbs it will simply not calculate.  Does anyone know how to make it split a single item that is over 150lbs and give a rate?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible.
The max package weight of 150  means that they don't ship anything over that value (I think).
So it means that in your case you cannot use that shipping method to deliver your products.

Comment: That is true 150 is the Max.  The issue is that Magento doesn't support multiple boxes for a single product.  We sell furniture where one item will come in 2 or 3 boxes (each box being under 150lbs and ups will ship it), however if we reduce the weight, the rate calculated will not be accurate.